# Cache directory was used before

Tags: java, android, android-studio, caching

I am trying to use android library bucket and when I run my app it is showing this error message

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache directory 
> /data/user/0/com.example.app/cache/Bucket was used before.
> ```

[from](https://github.com/simonpercic/Bucket)

Comment: Post the code you're using that causes this.  Do not link to code.  THe problem is either in the library or your use of the library, as this is not an ANdroid error.

Comment: Also-  I really wouldn't suggest using a library that isn't well known, has no releases, and a total of 40 commits over the course of 2 weeks and nothing in the last 3 years.  Nobody is maintaining or bug fixing this library.  I'd recommend not using random things you find on github, unless you've read the code and validated its bug free and non-malicious.